# For repeated paricular project numberI need to check all repeated rows has same boolean values using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Iam trying to get the boolean values of same project number which is repeated for several times is having same values in all the repeated rows of that particular project number.

this is what i have tried

```
SELECT
   PROJECTNUMBER
FROM
   table_name where boolean_column = 0
GROUP BY PROJECTNUMBER
HAVING count(boolean_column = 0)>1
```

but i get expected one and including of 0 and 1

what i want is

```
proj_numb | bool_column

PN-1 | 0

PN-1 | 0

PN-1 | 0
```

what i don't want is

```
proj_numb | bool_column

PN-1 | 0

PN-1 | 0

PN-1 | 1
```

Comment: Often handled with a where clause having an exists test. Do publish what you have tried (it would help convince that you are not seeking free consultancy)

Comment: just edited as you mention @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `pid` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boolval` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ;

+------+---------+
| pid  | boolval |
+------+---------+
| p1   |       0 |
| p1   |       0 |
| p1   |       1 |
| p2   |       0 |
| p2   |       0 |
| p2   |       0 |
+------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using an existence test

```
select * 
from t
where not exists(select 1 from t t1 where t1.pid = t.pid and boolval = 1);

+------+---------+
| pid  | boolval |
+------+---------+
| p2   |       0 |
| p2   |       0 |
| p2   |       0 |
+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```